# break tag is not working in an HTML in a string template literal tagged with the `html`

Tags: html, jquery, css, typescript, lit

This is a sample code where I am trying to add a break tag
 and \n inside the string for the newline but it is not working in the code.

I also tried with \n but this is also not working

Sample code:

```
import {html, css, LitElement} from 'lit';
import {customElement, property} from 'lit/decorators.js';

@customElement('simple-greeting')
export class SimpleGreeting extends LitElement {
  static styles = css`p { color: blue }`;

  @property()
  message = 'Hello!<br /> How are you?';

  render() {
    return html`<p>${this.name}!</p>`;
  }
}
```

Output:
`Hello! <br /> How are you?!`

Expected output:

Hello! 
How are you?!

Comment: I'm willing to bet this is because lit is parsing your html. Here are some [docs on setting unsafe html](https://lit.dev/docs/v1/lit-html/template-reference/#unsafehtml). Though it's usually advised against to dangerously set html, instead parse the html yourself for content and only pass along dynamic content.

Comment: Thank you! This solves when there is html tag in a string but when there is a **\n**, this does not work. Is there a way to also make this work?

Comment: If you want the display to preserve newline characters you should use the css property / value `white-space: pre-wrap;` on it's container  glad it could help!

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me to come up with a solution.

Using white-space: pre-wrap did solve to preserve the new line characters but some how the expression has additional new line characters which are preserving those too. I replaced the new line character in my message string with <br> tag and used the unsafehtml which did fix my issue.